# Azure Key Vault: Get/Delete/Set operations with KeyVaultClient in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I've seen many examples of Azure Key Vault used to retrieve secrets using `IConfiguration` including [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources) and [this](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/simplifying-azure-key-vault-and-net-core-web-app-includes-nuget-package/) however these mostly deal with viewing secrets and not CRUD type operations.

I'm trying to use the `IKeyVaultClient` extension methods like `GetSecretAsync` describe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.setsecretasync?view=azure-dotnet). To implement this I'm using a Managed Service Identity in Azure and have performed the following steps (outside the typical Azure config):

1. Create a public `IKeyVaultOps` interface and `KeyVaultOps` implementing public class containing the creation of a `KeyVaultClient`.

#### KeyVaultOps.cs

```
public class KeyVaultOps : IKeyVaultOps
{
    public KeyVaultClient GetKeyVaultClient()
    {
        AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        return new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    }
}
```

2. Use DI to inject where necessary:

#### Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IKeyVaultOps, KeyVaultOps>();
```

#### Razor page:

```
private readonly IKeyVaultOps keyVaultOps;
private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

public TestPageModel(
    IKeyVaultOps keyVaultOps,
    IConfiguration configuration
)
{
    this.keyVaultOps = keyVaultOps;
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

public string Secret { get; set; }

public class TestPageModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var vaultUrl = configuration["KeyVaultUrl"];
            SecretBundle secretBundle = await keyVaultOps.GetKeyVaultClient().GetSecretAsync(vaultUrl, "TestSecret");
            Secret = secretBundle.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Secret = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Recognizing I don't actually need an interface for this to work correctly, I'm looking for suggestions on two things:

1. Is there a better way to configure the `KeyVaultClient` URL property than injecting `IConfiguration` on every class I need the implementation?
2. Since my main project has `using` statements for `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault` anyway, is there a way to avoid my own `GetKeyVaultClient()` implementation and simply use:

   `services.AddSingleton<IKeyVaultClient, KeyVaultClient>();`

...along with the necessary extension methods?

NOTE: The above line in `Startup.cs` produces:

> No constructor for type 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values

Comment: For #2, you get that error because you haven't registered other types or instances that can fill in the parameters of any of `KeyVaultClient`s constructors, and the container can't build it. You could fix this by using one of the overloads of `AddSingleton` that lets you provide an instance or a factory (i.e. `AddSingleton<IKeyVaultClient>(new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(new AzureServiceTokenProvider().KeyVaultTokenCallback)));`, but that won't solve problem #1.

Comment: pretty sad state when a well formed question, which has no other credible references, gets cowardly down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to create my own service for accessing key vault that handles the URL and auth stuff for me, so my code can simply use the service without regard to configuration.  It works something like this:

```
public interface IMyKeyVaultClient {
   Task<SecretBundle> GetSecretAsync(string secretName);
}

public class MyKeyVaultClient : IMyKeyVaultClient {
   public MyKeyVaultClient(IConfiguration config, IWhateverElseYouNeedForGettingCredentials otherStuff) {
       //snag the URL from config and credentials from otherStuff
       //instantiate keyVaultClient;
   }
   private KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient;
   private string url;
   public Task<SecretBundle> GetSecretAsync(string secretName) {
       return keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(url, secretName);
   }
}
```

then register your service,

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyKeyVaultClient, MyKeyVaultClient>();
```

then your calling code can simply request an `IMyKeyVaultClient` from DI and call `GetSecretAsync()` with just a secret name and not have to worry about the details.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing that; the implementation in this answer is a very standard pattern. If you want to be able to call a version of `GetSecretAsync` that doesn't require a vault URL, this is how you'd do it.